# It possible to attach a handler for when an item is loaded to the DOM in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I know I can do this:

```
$("#my_div").live("click", function() {
  alert("My Div was clicked");
}
```

But how can I define a handler to call when a matching element is loaded to the DOM (now or in future)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Live Query](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery). It allow you to fire events when matching elements get added to the DOM.

Comment: isn't this the same as jQuery's live() method?

Comment: @bodacious: Sort of, livequery allows you to bind events and execute code as elements are loaded into the page. `.live()` is limited to certain events and does not allow arbitrary code to be executed on load, only when an event fires.

Comment: on closer inspection... this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to achieve this, without using a plug-in, is:

```
$('selecter').bind('DOMNodeInserted',
    function(){
        if ($('.newElementClassName').length > countOfNewDivs) {
            // new element matching new element's class-name has been added
            countOfNewDivs++;
            alert(countOfNewDivs);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PSJfD/).

#### **Note:**

This has only been tested on Chromium 11, and Firefox 4, on Ubuntu 11.04; I don't think that this approach is likely to work in IE, but I'm unable to test.

Answer (score -2):

One way of doing this is assigning all common divs the same class and using:

```
$(".myDIVClass").live("click", function() {
  alert("My Div was clicked");
}
```